# How to assign column with string values to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with multiple columns of which I want to return these 4 columns. There exist duplicates in the Case_ID column with a different start and or completion time. The goal is to return the case_id with the min start_time and max completion_time and the corresponding casetype.

```
Case_ID         Start_time   Completion_time   Casetype 

BZ-06-0501-001  2006-10-24  2007-06-15         'string'
BZ-06-0507-001  2006-10-30  2007-06-18         'string'
BZ-06-0508-001  2006-10-30  2008-09-08         'string'
BZ-06-0509-001  2006-10-30  2008-09-08         'string'
```

This is the code I use

```
def f():
    appeals = pd.read_csv('appeals')
    min_max = appeals[['Case_ID','Start_time','Completion_time']].groupby('Case_ID').agg({'Start_time' : ['min'], 'Completion_time' : ['max']}).assign(Casetype = appeals['Casetype'])
    return min_max
```

The problem is that the casetype column returns as nan. So the column the values in the column are not seen as a string anymore. Did I use assign() wrongly?

Comment: are the casetypes all the same for a given case_ID?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
min_max = appeals.groupby('Case_ID').agg({'Start_time' : 'min', 'Completion_time' : 'max', 'Casetype': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

I removed your selection of columns (`[['Case_ID','Start_time','Completion_time']]`) in order to keep all the columns, including `Casetype`. Then, I added `Casetype` in the aggregation, with the selection of the first occurence, as you said all `Casetype` are the same for a given `Case_ID`. Then, I removed the `.assign()`.